# Polymorphism,STL,find and operator==

Tags: c++, stl

I ran into a problem.
I have a class A,and a class that inherits from A,lets call it class B.
I have virtual functions.
I want to compare A and B to another class C by operator==.
If i want to have a list of A's,lets say in stl list,
I must use a pointer to A,so it will look like:

```
list<*A> list;
```

and also i have: `C something`

but now,i cant use the function:`find(list.begin(),list.end(),something)`
because i cant use operator == for pointers(*).

I found a solution but i dont think its the best,so my question is-can i do it better?

```
    iter=list.begin();
    for(iter;iter!=list.end();++iter)
    {
        if((*iter).operator==(something)
            return ...
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `find_if`, which lets you provide a function to check for equal values.

```
auto check_something = 
     [&something](const list<*A>::iterator& iter){return *iter == something; };

find_if(list.begin(),list.end(),check_something)
```

Comment: what is the syntax "auto"?

Comment: @Anton It is one of the new features of C++11. The compiler generally knows what the return type of an right hand side expression (a lambda in this case) is. Since you pass this to a template function, you do not need to know the real type. In this special case `check_something` would be of type `std::function<bool(const list<*A>::iterator)>`. If you cannot use C++11, an alternative is to write a struct that aggregates something and provides`operator(const list<*A>::iterator&)` with the content of the lambda above.

Comment: can i have a way to do that without auto function?
i mean,fucntion that checks somthing accroding to a variable that i get as an input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(**iter == something)
```

if you want to dereference the pointer.

In C++1x, there is also

```
for(auto ptr : list)
    if(*ptr == something)
```

Comment: the first thing is actually the same as i did,
what is c++1x?

is there another way to do what i did with stl find func?

Comment: @Anton: "C++1x" is a typo for "C++11", the current standard. (It was informally known as "C++0x" before it became the standard two years ago, which is probably how the "x" got there).

Comment: C++1x is what we used to call C++14.

Comment: @bstamour: That was known as C++1y, to (supposedly) avoid confusion. And the code here is fine in C++11.

Comment: @Mike, you're right - my bad. And yes it is valid C++11 code, I never claimed otherwise. 1x is just an alpha-reduction away from 1y anyways ;-)

Comment: snarky people call it C++0x0x.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing says you can't make a global non-member `operator ==` that operates on *pointers* or combinations of pointers and objects.  If you have many types you could template the combination of pointer vs object equality for any type.

Edit to add this tip:  Put the comparison in a namespace with your objects and then argument dependent lookup will find it without putting a global `T* == T` in scope that catches everything:

```
namespace equals {
    struct A {
        A(int x) :x(x) { }
        bool operator == (const A &other) const {
            return other.x == x;
        }
        int x;
    };

    template <typename T>
    bool operator == (const T *lhs, const T &rhs) {
        return *lhs == rhs;
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator == (const T &lhs, const T *rhs) {
        return lhs == *rhs;
    }
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
equals::A b(1), c(1);
if (b == &c) std::cerr << "good!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html) which is designed for just this purpose.

```
find(
    boost::make_indirect_iterator( list.begin() ),
    boost::make_indirect_iterator( list.end() ),
    something );
```

Comment: is that something new in c++?

Comment: No, Boost is a widely used collection of high quality libraries.  Many parts of it have gone on to become (or at least inspire) standardized C++.  To the best of my knowledge however, there is nothing like `indirect_iterator` currently available in the standard library.

Comment: @Anton (forgot to tag you in previous comment).